# SQL concatenate - reorder a date from European to US format

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

SQL Novice here. I am trying to reorder a date from European to US format and having trouble. I'm getting the AS field names rather than the date result that I need. The code and results are below:

```
Select LEFT([Value_date],2) AS DayParse, 
    Substring ([Value_date],4,3) AS MonthParse, 
    Right([Value_date],5) AS YearParse, 
    'MonthParse' + 'DayParse' + 'YearParse' As Value_Date_Reorder 
From [RAW].[dbo].[RAW_DERIVATIVES]


DayParse    MonthParse  YearParse   Value_Date_Reorder      
30          06/         /2017       MonthParseDayParseYearParse
```

Comment: Store dates as date/time values and use `convert()` to convert them to strings using the appropriate format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Value_date is DATETIME type, I suggest the below query.
You have to concatenate the original data.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(MONTH, Value_date)) + '/' 
+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(DAY, Value_date)) 
+ '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART (YEAR, Value_date)) AS Value_Date_Reorder
FROM [RAW].[dbo].[RAW_DERIVATIVES]
ORDER BY 1
```